# How to set a configurable download location for a file through Spring Boot Rest Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In my REST API I want to download a file into a configurable location on disk, I managed to implement the download functionality but I can't get that Save As window in browser(I use Chrome).
This is the response entity that I return into my get method

```
  public ResponseEntity<Object> download() throws IOException {
    
    String fileName = "fileDownload.txt";
    File file = objService.getFile();

    return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION
                    ,String.format("attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\""))
            .body(new ByteArrayResource(new FileInputStream(file).readAllBytes()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add a contentType to ur response, Try using :

```
@GetMapping("/download/{fileName:.+}")
public ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource> download(@PathVariable String fileName) throws IOException {
   File file = new File(UPLOADED_FOLDER + fileName);
   // return 404 if file not exist or ResponseEntity.noContent().build();

   HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
   headers.add("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+fileName+"\"");
   // add other header, ex: Cache-Control...


   Path path = Paths.get(UPLOADED_FOLDER + fileName);
   ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(Files.readAllBytes(path));

   return ResponseEntity.ok()
       .headers(headers)
       .contentLength(file.length())
       .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
       .body(resource);
 }
```

Comment: It still doesn't work

Comment: Could u plz, check your browser config to enable "Save As":  
=> Open the Google Chrome browser.  
=> Click the three-dotted icon on top-right and select Settings.  
=> Click the Advanced option. and  Select Downloads.  
=> Toggle the Ask where to save each file before downloading button.